# What is this on my lawn?

Tags: lawn, pests

I saw a suspicious flock of birds all over my lawn today.

I went over to inspect the areas they where pecking, and saw this:

[image]

In the past it has been grubs, but seems 1. late in season and 2. doesn't look like grubs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sure looks like rabbit droppings - otherwise known as "nature's fertilizer" :)

Comment: ... and the birds were probably feeding on insects that were feeding on or laying their eggs in the rabbit poo.